# string between parentheses with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This javascript regex needs to extract "131PS" from "this is (131PS) for now".
Then I need to get "131" as a number and "PS" as a string.
Any suggestions? thx

```
 myString.match(/\(([^\)]+)\)/ig)[0]
```

returns (131PS) which is not what was expected.

Comment: `arr = myString.match(/\((\d+)([a-z]+)\)/i)` and use `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`

Comment: Use `[1]` to get the value in first captured group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with capture regex groups `()` to withdraw the number and string separately, have a look:

```js
let rawStr = "this is (131PS) for now";

let theMatch = rawStr.match(/\((\d+)([A-Z]+)\)/);

if (theMatch) {
  let theNum = parseInt(theMatch[1]);
  let theString = theMatch[2];
  
  console.log(theNum, theString);
}
```

Comment: @Tushar thanks for mentioning it's not needed in this example I edited the example. Please take a look again.